# Reputation points for images is a problem for visual languages

Tags: discussion, images, languages

There are questions on StackOverflow about LabVIEW, a graphical programming language. A new user does not have enough reputation points to post images with their questions, but for any graphical language, that is akin to saying a new C programmer doesn't have enough points to post text code -- kind of limits the usefulness of StackOverflow.

Is there anyway to carve an exception to the points limitation when a question has a tag of a known visual language? Can we allow a single image at least?

Comment: You can add up to two links to your question. If any of those are images, the community is usually more than happy to convert those links to embedded images. The restriction is lifted when you reach 10 points, hardly a big hurdle.

Comment: I feel your pain.  The problem is that LabVIEW code is much less searchable than other code.  You're basically searching for the VI block names anyway.  And for the small amount of traffic on SO for LabVIEW, it's really not too much trouble for the low rep user to request someone else edit in the picture for them.  Most people go to ni.com for LabVIEW anyway.

Comment: 10 pts rep isn't that much hurdle!

Comment: I know about the ability for later editors to convert the image over. How about this... when user clicks on the button to add an image, instead of just saying they don't have enough points, can we explicitly note that the community will generally convert an image over if it is a valuable image?

Comment: @srm Of course non-spammers will think all their images are important.  That doesn't really fix anything.  And I'm sure that people active in LabVIEW on SO already have solutions for this common problem.

Comment: I agree it isn't *much* of a hurdle, but I'm trying to find a way to lower it even further. It's a substantial wall if you come to ask a question and you can't easily do so, and it is a peculiarity of visual languages to need this more than the majority of languages.

Comment: > And I'm sure that people active in LabVIEW on SO already have solutions for this common problem.   --- yes, the majority don't use StackOverflow and lament the lack of the excellent voting facilities. They use lavag.org and ni.com instead.

Comment: Well, the answers are pretty resoundingly, "No, there's nothing to be done." Pity. I'll vote to close the question.

Comment: @srm nuance here. It's not "no there's nothing to be done". It's "the system is working as expected, there is no reason to make a special case here". Also, if the majority of LabVIEW users go on other sites because they can't be bothered to get 10 rep on stack (1 upvote on answers, 2 on questions, or 5 edits accepted)... would they be good users in the long run?

Comment: 10 points is *one* upvote. That can't be hard to attain for someone using a piece of software as complex as Labview seems to be

Comment: @Pekka웃 10 rep on answers, 5 rep on questions. So for a new *asker* it would be two upvotes. That said, still trivial if the question is a good question.

Comment: _can we explicitly note that the community will generally convert an image over_ - Is the concern that people won't think to link to an image if they can't place it in the question?

Comment: Weighing the pros and cons, I don't think this is a terrible suggestion. It would give spammers an open door, but LabVIEW is such a niche language that the door would be awfully narrow. I doubt they'd even notice. Unfortunately, it's such a low-traffic tag that I doubt anyone else would either, so any spam might survive on the site for some time.

Comment: For what it is worth, I would not do it at all - less headaches and it really is not that much to get enough rep to post images (except for the melodramatic people).

Comment: @BSMP: Correct, especially when there are other sites that make it easy to do so. I don't understand the spam complaint, honestly. Other forums seem to allow posting of images just fine... how does image spam differ from text spam? Isn't the defense the same?

Comment: @Patrice I wager most text programmer's first action on StackOverflow is to ask a question, rather than upvoting existing answers. Upvoting is something I only started doing after realizing the value of the exchanges is in the meta content.

Comment: @santiago "not that much"? A new user need to earn 10 rep to post images. A new user needs to answer a question to earn 10 rep. A new user needs to post images to answer questions about LabVIEW. So where should a new user start? Or must a new user first become an expert in a language other than LabVIEW and answer questions in that language first?

Comment: @tepples they could do 5 edits (2 rep each), ask a question or two...

Comment: @santiago Asking a LabVIEW question also needs 10 rep.

Comment: then 5 edits will give a member the 10 points

Comment: @tepples and you can post a question with a link to an image. If the question is valid, people WILL edit the image in it.

Comment: @Patrice: Strike the condition and you are closer to the truth, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) based on the work the team put in to resolve [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/307500) feature request.

To summarize the link: Users with < 10 reputation can now post images (up to 2 due to link restrictions).  The post will still need to be edited by someone with > 10 reputation to change the markdown from:

```
[image alt][1]
```

to:

```
![image alt][1] or [![image alt][1]][1]
```

It's important that when enabling image embedding in a post, the editor carefully checks the image to make sure that it's allowed content. As in, the image is not blatantly inappropriate (NSFW), offensive, or otherwise abusive. Also, make sure to correct as many other things wrong with the post as you can. If the image is the only problem with the post, you'll have to have >2k reputation, because of the minimum size of a suggested edit.

New users are also presented with the warning:

> [image]

*(Stole [bluefeet ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet)'s screenshot from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/5240004))*

Edited to add that I'm **not** a member of the team.

Comment: Also, those who *can*, *should* abstain from editing to embed the image unless the image is used properly (not NSFW, not code nor other textual data, the image is either supplementary or there's no way to describe the essential parts sufficienty anyway.)

Comment: This was a bad change. People are just posting screenshots of code (when they should be posting the text), and sub-2k users are suggesting edits to turn the links into embedded images. Total garbage and a waste of time for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

At this point I agree with a comment by santiago: Before posting your own question or answer, edit five existing posts.

Find five different posts (questions or answers) with errors in grammar, usage, or mechanics, or *minor* errors in fact, and edit these posts while logged in to your account.
But be careful not to change the meaning of a post, and make sure to fix *all* problems with the post, not just the one that you see first.
When you edit a post, you'll see the Markdown source code that makes it up, and in most browsers, you'll get a real-time preview of how the post will be rendered.
If high-reputation users accept your edits as improvements, you'll get two points for each.
While you wait for other users to evaluate your edits, consider reading the resources in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly how [Markdown formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) works, what makes a good question or answer, and what is on-topic for each SE site.
So long as you don't try more than five edits per week before [three-fourths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337) of your edits are helpful, suggested edits can be a useful tool to learn Markdown and community expectations.

Here are some targets for your first few suggested edits:

- Posts by non-native English speakers whose English needs correcting.
- Posts by other new users whose code formatting (in a non-visual language) needs correcting. Some people haven't yet figured out how to indent blocks of code by four spaces or put backticks around keywords or variable names referred to in prose.
- Posts that spell "Stack Overflow" or "Stack Exchange" other than as described in [Stack Exchange's trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance). Most posts referring to Stack Exchange branding will be on child metas, which you can't edit, but there are plenty on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and they occasionally pop up elsewhere, such as on [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/how-can-i-explain-to-my-child-that-im-not-superman) and [The Workplace](//workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/is-stack-exchange-use-a-valuable-skill-on-my-cv/50254#50254). If you have 180 or more reputation on another Stack Exchange site, search for the single word `"stackoverflow"` or `"stackexchange"` there and change them to two words in title case ("Stack Overflow" or "Stack Exchange") if needed. There are also plenty of "stackoverflow" on Stack Overflow itself, mostly referring to overflows of the stack in C or C++. You need to include the quotation marks in the query because Stack Exchange search [automatically converts a lone unquoted keyword to a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags) if it is one of the top few dozen tags on a site.
- If you have 180 reputation on Mathematics Stack Exchange, you could [correct a few Lebesque to Lebesgue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque) there and claim your association bonus.

Again, remember to fix *all* problems with each post.

Comment: one sidenote : editing on meta stack exchange will give you points on THAT site, not here

Comment: @Patrice There are so many posts on MSE containing `"stackexchange"` or `"stackoverflow"` that a few dozen people could get the association bonus just by fixing them. There are thousands of `"stackoverflow"` on SO main as well, though those are predominantly "Posts [...] whose English needs correcting".

Comment: definitely on board with that. But your answer won't last in time, since there won't be THAT many posts on MSE as people start following your tips ;)

Comment: I wonder... if we put a requirement in that all text users have to edit five posts before they can post code... how much of a dip occurs in first-time questions being asked would occur? Oh well... at least I can say I tried to get this situation improved. Thank you for your time.