# Are questions about pseudo-programming software on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I think I just made up the word "pseudo-programming software". What I mean is those programs which allow you to drag and drop "blocks" to the editor and kind of "write code". For example, Scratch and the MIT app inventor.

These software are usually user-friendly and are often regarded as "not programming". But they often contain concepts such as loops, if statements, variables, and even functions!

I just want to ask whether questions like:

- what is the Java equivalent of XXX in app inventor?
- Scratch - when I do XXX, YYY occurred, why?
- How do I turn a scratch project into an exe file

Are on topic for stackoverflow. If not, where should people ask them on?

Comment: If it is Turing-complete, it IMHO should stay here. (Unless it has to do with unix, server administration, exploits, matlab, mathcad, emacs, vim... you get my drift).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-inventor

Comment: If the user really needs and wants to know "what is the <language> equivallent of XXX in app inventor", the user should really be *familiar* with the <language> and have thorough experience with app inventor. Otherwise, it may be just a "please do/port my homework" in disguise.

Comment: To piggyback off Shark's comment, I almost never like "what's the XXX equivalent of foo in YYY?" questions. They require that I know both XXX and YYY, but if you just explained it in terms of what you want to do (in "absolute" terms, not relative to XXX), then I only need to know YYY to answer it. They also tend to pollute tags: people tend to tag XXX in the question, but it's really a question about YYY, and the XXX is only there to provide a shorthand problem description. It's okay to mention XXX for color, but imo the question shouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Reputation points for images is a problem for visual languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303624/reputation-points-for-images-is-a-problem-for-visual-languages)

Since they've made an exception for posting images for visual programming languages (rather than just saying "don't ask these questions here") I'd say that the official word is that these are considered on topic. That question is specifically about Labview but it looks like the same sort of thing as AppInventor and Scratch

Labview:
[Labview : numbering color box array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446287/labview-numbering-color-box-array)

AppInventor:
[Proper way of using ResultNotifier.ShowProgressDialog in App Inventor 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780790/proper-way-of-using-resultnotifier-showprogressdialog-in-app-inventor-2)

Scratch:
[Simulating a custom reporter block in Scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948249/simulating-a-custom-reporter-block-in-scratch)
(This one actually has text for the code)