# How to review edits that add images?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In each scenario the OP has linked to an image and the Suggested Editor has used the URL to add the image to the post itself.

**Screenshots of text**

[We don't want users posting screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) whether it's code, error messages, or even the homework question they're working on.

I keep seeing suggested edits where users are adding these text images to the post. Assuming this is the only edit in the post, should this be rejected as no improvement? It seems silly to allow it only to tell the OP to take it back out but I couldn't shake the feeling that rejecting it would still be seen as wrong.

Note that none of these edits ever include alt-text.

**Useful images without alt-text**

I've only seen two suggested edits that even changed the "enter image description here" placeholder and only one of those actually described what was in the image.

Assuming again that adding the image is the only change, is this also reject worthy? In this case I'm talking about non-text images that actually add to the post.

**Images that aren't useful**

The first two situations are fairly common but every once in a while I see an image addition that just doesn't help the post at all. The OP, for whatever reason, linked to a screenshot that's either incomprehensible or simply doesn't support the post in any way.

An example of the latter would be a question about not being able to create a specific component in an app and the image would be a screenshot of the launch screen.

Should I be treating images like this as noise? If adding this image is the only change to a post, should I reject it?

Knowing how to handle these cases when there are no other problems with the post will allow me to figure out whether I should Improve & Edit or Reject & Edit when they aren't the only change and/or the post has other issue.

Comment: Why is the alt-text a problem? That doens't show anywhere except the raw-text of the post right? i.e. one has to click "edit" to be able to read it. I never could be bothered to add a proper alt-text if I use a single image, not for my own posts, not when editing posts of others, since it doesn't show anyway.

Comment: @Adriaan That is used to set the [`alt` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-alt) of the image, which is used when the image cannot be loaded or is not loaded yet. It is also [used by screen readers](http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/), so for people with a visual impairment. You add an alt text for those people and for people that try to read the post in a future where the image link died.

Comment: @Adriaan Pretty much what Just a student said. There are also people who can't see images because they're blocked. Basically, the assumption that everyone can see the image is false. Any question relying on an image to convey information without any text (alt-text or otherwise) to describe it is going to be unclear to anyone who cant' see it.

Comment: If it is a screenshot of text, reject the edit and ask op to post the code or vote to close.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Screenshots of text

**If an edit proposes an image of code, then that edit should be rejected.** Period.

The only acceptable edit in this case is one that *transcribes* the code into the question. This can come from the original poster, or it can come from some other benefactor, but that's the edit that needs to happen.

Editing in the screenshot just edits in pointlessness and contributes to the delinquency by rewarding the person who posted the broken question in the first place.

> Useful images without alt-text

This is not, in itself, sufficient reason to reject. This is a good reason to "Improve" (Approve and Edit), so that you can add the alt text yourself. (Or, at the very least, remove the useless "enter image description here" if there is no reasonable alt text that could be provided.)

Otherwise, you might want to reject (maybe "Reject and Edit") if the post had many other glaring problems that the edit failed to fix, such as broken code formatting. I refuse to reward people for doing half-arsed work. You might not catch *everything* that's wrong, but you should catch the big obvious stuff, otherwise you're not really helping the situation and mostly wasting reviewers' time.

> Images that aren't useful

Um yeah. Edits that edit in useless things should be rejected. Nothing surprising here.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the first point.  It, in my opinion, directly defeating one of the reasons we prevent low rep users from directly posting visible images instead of links.

Comment: "*If an edit proposes an image of code, then that edit should be rejected. Period.*" I generally agree, but lets not forget that some images may only look like they are about problem with code, but in reality they are about ***problem with editor/IDE handling the code*** like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335263/intellij-deprecation-warning-for-java-util-hashmap (although to avoid such confusion reviewer could improve image with some freehand cycles highlighting the problem - not that I mentioned it maybe it is time to use that advice).

Comment: Yes, it is also a good idea to at least skim the question before making a decision about the edit. :-)

Comment: How should one transcribe "G" dataflow diagrams in LabVIEW? Is one expected to manually turn it into a pile of ASCII art, which manual conversion itself is likely to produce errors?

Comment: @damian Are "'G' dataflow diagrams in LabVIEW" considered "code"? If not, then no. You don't need to transcribe them into ASCII. My answer doesn't suggest that. It simply says that edits proposing images of code should be rejected, not that all images are bad.

Comment: Yes, G in LabVIEW is considered its visual programming language.

Comment: @DamianYerrick There's [an exception for programming languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315404/are-questions-about-pseudo-programming-software-on-topic/315408#315408). I would still expect to see alt text explaining what it is, even if it's just, "Screenshot of code for a visual programming language. The code's behavior is described above."

Comment: Despite this policy getting agreed on, I'm still seeing edits that embed screenshots of code getting approved, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19272220.  Should I just drop a comment asking the editor not to do this, pointing back to this question?

Comment: *The only acceptable edit in this case is one that transcribes the code into the question. This can come from ... some other benefactor...* - this statement conflicts somewhat with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246: ***Don't:** Transcribe code from an image to text. It's just too easy to introduce new errors.*  Can we get some agreement on this?  Should the answer there be updated to say that external images of code should not get embedded either?

Comment: Do the transcription without making errors, @dbc. A transcription error is grounds to reject. The tendency to make transcription errors is why we generally discourage people from doing it (see also: "polishing turds" and "optimizing for pearls"). But if they choose to do so, and the transcription is correct, then the effort *was* helpful and should be approved.

Answer (score 9):

The thought process for reviewing suggested edits shouldn't change just because there's an image being inserted.

It is still a matter of deciding if the post is improved by the edit.

So, to your specific points:

- Useful images without alt-text - Improve the edit by adding the text, that is the smallest courtesy for our visually impaired members.
- Useless images - Reject, at the very least it is "*No improvement
  whatsoever*".

Answer (score 3):

While I largely agree with [Cody](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350228/241211), the point that [Pshemo makes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350212/how-to-review-edits-that-add-images?cb=1#comment479248_350228) is important: In rare cases, an image is more helpful for sighted visitors. On one of my questions, I started with plaintext, but ended up [editing in a supplemental screenshot for clarity.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39044409/241211) If Markdown allowed line breaks in image alt-text, I might have gone image-only.

If the problem can be demonstrated without an image, even with a `// <-- this line` comment, I say *Reject & Edit* and transcribe the text. If, however, the problem relies on

- Non-syntax highlighting in code or ascii tables, *or*
- Text formatting that cannot be approximated in Markdown in non-code,

Then use a screenshot with a reasonably descriptive alt-text caption.

Comment: Transcribe the text?? Disagree - that's not going to teach the OP to do it correctly. I mostly reject as 'No improvement', and also leave a comment to OP with a link to the meta post about screenshots of text. Also, (and perhaps most importantly), you may mask the problem by inadvertently correcting a typo or introduce another one.