# Ask Wizard for New Users Feature Test is complete

Tags: discussion, new-users, a-b-testing, ask-question-wizard

**Update**: This feature test was live on Stack Overflow from 2022-03-21 through 2022-04-06. The overall results from this test were very positive and are available [in a separate post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418491/ask-wizard-test-results-and-next-steps).

---

A couple of weeks ago we previewed details about the upcoming [Ask Wizard for New Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/upcoming-feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users) feature test. Please see the preview post for a general overview of the methodology and layout. A list of changes implemented since the announcement is below.

The experiment will stay live until we have been able to collect the test data that we need to evaluate the changes here (which should be no more than two weeks).

#### Changes since the original announcement

As noted above, a number of changes were made to the Wizard since the original announcement, many in direct response to feedback given there. Here are the big changes:

- *Similar posts*

  - Has been moved from after the *Title* step to be after the *Tags* step
  - Now includes contents of tags when making post suggestions
  - Is hidden on the final review step, but will reappear if there are any changes to the Title or Tags of the post (which would cause the Similar posts suggestions to refresh)
- A whole bunch of tweaks to on-screen copy in section subheaders and sidebars
- Images

  - In the editor, new users will be able to post images (since previously they would just end up posting links to images, which is less helpful). We will monitor this to see if this results in a degradation of quality.
  - Additional instructions on the proper and improper use of images is provided:

    [image: New text added to the sidebar instructions: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately.]
- Posts created through the wizard will have a `PostHistory` entry that will identify the new question in timeline and revision history as having been created through the wizard.

Note: the new Ask Wizard will be the first step for all new users who will be asking questions in the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp) (more details on how that project will work coming soon). We are testing this first in order to be able to isolate the difference that the wizard alone make in our success metrics.

#### Want to try it out yourself?

During the experiment, 50% of users who would qualify for the First questions review queue will be shown the new Wizard, and 50% will be given the current Ask screen. However, even if you are not able to access the new Wizard organically through the test, anyone can load up the Wizard and use it for posting a question by going to **[/questions/ask?force-wizard=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?force-wizard=true)**. Users who access and use the Wizard through querystring, who are not already included in the experiment, will not affect the experiment (we will not include these posts when we evaluate the data).

Any feedback or bug reports on the operation of the Wizard are welcome as answers on this post.

Comment: I really hope the decision to allow easier uploading to images  won't result in an influx of more images of code/errors. I suspect, however, that it'll increase the volume of images of data we see; but one can hope that this isn't true.

Comment: @Larnu It does at least warn against that explicitly in the info box on the right: *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images)"*, so fingers crossed 

Comment: @Larnu We were allowing uploading of images anyway for new users - just forced them to post the images as links. But we'll just have to see how things play out with this. We are also looking into adding a popover for users as they activate the `insert image` event, that will give them a popover saying this stuff more explicitly (didn't have time to get it in for this release).

Comment: It does, @NickstandswithUkraine, but considering many new users don't even read the [tour], which they are taken to after they sign up, I'm sceptical they'll read that. I am, however, more than happy to be proved wrong, and that they do in fact, end up reading the modal. :)

Comment: @YaakovEllis *"We are also looking into adding a popover for users as they activate the insert image event, that will give them a popover saying this stuff more explicitly (didn't have time to get it in for this release)."* - Nice! Please do! :D

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine like I said, on a list of nice-to-have things that we hope to add in the future. And another good thing about using the Stacks Editor: makes things like this relatively easy (versus relatively impossible with the old editor).

Comment: Is it possible for a user to both be in the wizard test and in the new mentorship/staging ground program? That would lead to the _superbestest_ questions ever...! More seriously, what is the relation between the two initiatives?

Comment: @Marijn when the staging ground test goes live (more details on that in upcoming posts), the Ask Wizard will be the feeder. All new questions will go in through the new wizard. Part of the reason for the test here is to see how big an impact of the wizard has by itself. I will update the post above to include this as well.

Comment: _“Now includes contents of tags when making post suggestions”_ — That is interesting. Does it work the same way as the suggestions list in the duplicate close dialog? Or is one suggestions list more “advanced” than the other? I think both lists are still not quite as useful because they don’t consider the post body.

Comment: @SebastianSimon This works in a way that should be more exact than the suggestions list in the duplicate close dialog.

Comment: Have you considered adding, near the top, links to the RU, PT and ES versions of Stack Overflow? We seem to get quite a lot of posts in those languages on the main site.

Comment: @Mat we are not planning on that here. However, there is another feature in the works (that we will hopefully be able to announce and try out soon) that should help with detecting when questions are written in the wrong language and with providing guidance for users on where to post their questions in those cases.

Comment: An unfortunate side-effect of the Markdown/WYSIWYG editor is that when you paste your code when Markdown is switched off (outside of a code block), it will escape all characters that have a meaning in markdown with a backslash, making it _al lot_ harder to format ill formatted posts. Now we have to manually remove all those backslashes if we want to fix the post. Even worst is that when you paste HTML _with Markdown switched on_ and then switch it off and on again, it will also add all those backslashes.

Comment: @Ivar This has just been reported: [Punctuation characters being escaped in code](/q/416802/4642212). Yes, switching “Markdown” mode off and on is a destructive action, which is [yet another problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/360159/289905) with the new Stacks editor.

Comment: Since the [new Stacks editor is still quite broken](/a/416331/4642212) we get problems like these: [Is the new editor's inline code tool supposed to break up code blocks?](/q/416801/4642212). Such posts are quickly downvoted. How will this be addressed in the evaluation in the experiment?

Comment: Am I the only person who visited the ask page with force wizard just to try it out, then clearing all the contents of my "question" instead of posting it?

Comment: @code I have yet to use the new editor and *not* have it loose everything I entered, at least once, when trying to compose or substantially edit a post.

Comment: This test does not seem to include the one most important thing in my opinion. A post can be made that is mostly just an image of code and the text "*help me I tried everything*"

Comment: @JonSG we can't prevent stuff like that. A question that comes in like that should deservedly be closed very quickly. Even after we put in a planned feature to get a user to affirm that they aren't posting an image of code, we can't prevent it. Preventing this isn't the goal of the project.

Comment: How on earth is this the name of a new feature? Did you run the initial title through ell.stackexchange first? "Ask Wizard" >.<  "Question Wizard" is arguably, slightly less awkward.

Comment: I imagine that "Ask Wizard" is a shortened version of the full name, "Ask-a-Question Wizard", @enhzflep.

Comment: @CodyGray - That's the obvious conclusion. Perhaps I can say something useful in the following manner. When using spreadsheet software, one occasionally needs to draw a chart or a figure. Draw being the action and Chart/Figure being the object created. There are of course wizards for it. Being the most widespread, surely, you know the name of Microsoft's offering to be Chart Wizard. Not the Draw wizard, nor the Draw Picture one or the Draw Figure one.
It's simply the Chart Wizard. As such, I suggest that the word "ask" has no place in its name. It's awkward and arguably, adds nothing.

Comment: "new users will be able to post images (since previously they would just end up posting links to images, which is less helpful)" I don't know how anyone could think this or be so out of touch. Does design staff not look at posts by new users? Allowing posting images validates what is extremely likely to be inappropriate behaviour. This is very very bad and the reason very very wrong. A popover will not help, it will be ignored. A popover should tell the asker that just putting a link in is probably a  bad idea.

Comment: dropping limitation to post images is ["an invitation for all sorts of spammers and trolls to learn how to automate their way of dumping trash via Ask Wizard...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421175/839601)

Comment: *In the editor, new users will be able to post images (since previously they would just end up posting links to images, which is less helpful). We will monitor this to see if this results in a degradation of quality.*  I am already seeing a degradation in quality as more and more posts contain images instead of code.  Please undo the damage of this.  Was this change ever discussed and approved by the community?

Comment: Because, in the opinion of the community which has been settled for years, links to images of code are not *less helpful* than embedded images of code.  Both are equally unhelpful, see [How to review edits that add images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350212/3744182) for confirmation.  In fact allowing code screen shots to be embedded may be worse as new users will think it's OK to take a snapshot of their code with their phone, and post that.  Please undo the damage of this change.

Answer (score 37):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Please make the "title" step be after the body/tags step, or at *least* not first.

Ref:

- [The answer requesting this on the last post that went unaddressed/unacknowledged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416353/2756409)
- [My well-received recommendation for an Asking Wizard from 2017 put the title last](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard)
- [SO's own previous Asking Wizard from 2018, which got it somewhat right by not putting the title first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype)
- [Putting title after body (and ideally after tags) makes it easier to find and show related duplicates when a potentially duplicate question title is entered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/ask-wizard-for-new-users-feature-test-is-now-live#comment900605_416738)

Comment: Agreed. I was taught in school from 4th grade on that you should write essays in the order: main body, conclusion, introduction, then title last. In university, I was taught to write papers in the order: main body, conclusion, abstract, then title last. When I started first using the Internet in the mid-90s, I was taught to write emails in the order: main body, conclusion, abstract, then subject last. And I believe I am not the only one, this seems to be pretty much the universal advice on good (technical) writing. Not sure where tags would fit in, but probably second-to-last.

Comment: @JörgWMittag tags would fit into the "keywords" category when you submit an academic paper. Ironically enough, they are the only ones that break the narrative as the advice used to be to add them after the abstract. That said, scientific journals don't usually have systems for "duplicate" submissions :)

Comment: This is something that we would consider for a future iteration on the wizard, but it wont go into the current version being tested.

Comment: So you're expecting the users to write the body before entering the title to then find out it's a duplicate? For me, [@Dalija's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416748/692942) makes more sense, move tags up below the title.

Comment: @user692942 Yes, absolutely. They should have searched for an existing solution before spending time writing a question. A user finding out there is an existing question already after spending time writing up a question will be a valuable lesson on doing some research ahead of time. Given the in-site search is horrible at finding duplicates compared to, say, Google, we don't want them to rely on it any more than they have to.

Comment: @TylerH but most don't. So one of the purposes of the Ask wizard is to point them in that direction which if it happens after they've spent time writing out the body of the question is going to infuriate them.

Comment: I'll accept that drawback when the upside is better titles. Prompting for the body and tags first ought to greatly reduce people's tendencies to shove their first sentence and language tags into the title field. Not to mention, better titles will make dupe searching more reliable. The dupe searcher has no hope with a title like, "Hey guys first time poster I could use your help with this problem - Java - Ubuntu 18.04".

Comment: @user692942 I posit that a little bit of infuriating of such users is exactly what's in order. If we can hit every first-time asker with one instance of "seriously, this question has already been asked?!" think how quickly the duplicate question rate will drop. And like John says, this will lead to far better titles, which I consider another win.

Comment: Ideally, you want to intervene early. The more time a person spends composing their question, the more they feel it's unique and special and *totally* not a duplicate.

Comment: @Ian I'd rather have better titles and more accurate duplicate searches than give users warm fuzzy feelings about their questions.

Comment: Ian's point is that the problem with putting the title and tags after the question body is that then the user has written an entire question before the system has a summary to search for a duplicate by, leading to attachment and sunk cost fallacy. Maybe there's a compromise here. What if the wizard forced the user to look over their title again after writing the question? Sure, a lot of users wouldn't bother rethinking it, but those users aren't interested in writing a good question anyway. Those that are actually trying would get a gentle reminder after having flushed out the question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But writing an SO question is *not* like writing an essay or article. Essays and articles attempt to **answer** some question. Writing an SO question is comparable to a step that is not even explicitly captured in the final version of the essay: the formulation of the question or problem before the essay is even started. At most, writing a question encompasses part of the research phase, where you learn more about the problem beforehand, and having the title and tags early allows SO itself to better assist in that research process before the user spends a lot of time writing.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, and I'm saying that attachment and sunk cost is a feature. If the *stack overflow* search (which is notoriously bad) can find a duplicate of your question, chances are you should have searched for it harder before typing up your question. There are some users who ask well-researched questions when joining the site, but overwhelmingly that is not the case. Forcing the users who have asked well-researched questions to look through a few potential duplicates that don't apply is a *great* price to pay for teaching new users the hard-ish way that they need to do more research.

Comment: @TylerH What are you talking about? The result of attachment and sunk cost fallacy is people posting garbage questions that have been asked a hundred times before. This is because they wrote the question *before* they searched much for an answer, and the wizard in no way forces (or even encourages as far as I can tell) doing your own research beforehand. How is people posting questions they shouldn't a net positive for anyone, particularly when it can be averted?

Comment: @jpmc26 because people post questions they shouldn't _right now_ and it's a big problem, because when they are dupes they either ignore the duplicate finder _right now_ (or it just doesn't find the duplicates). If we force them to put effort into their _question_ first, it will lead to a better title, which will mean the duplicate finder has a better chance of working. And you should think of the time spent formulating the question as 'research effort' rather than 'wasted time' since you seem hung up on that.

Comment: @jpmc26 Here is the outcome you would get: users spend more time practicing/working on crafting a good question. The site gets fewer dupes posted, or at worst, the same amount. It is win/win, or at the very least win/no-change. The negative reinforcement of "there's already a question that covers that?!" after writing up a question serves as a double whammy to put more effort into the process _before_ clicking "submit" on a question, **which is the whole point** of any effort like an ask question wizard or a staging ground, etc: to make sure questions that get posted on the site are better

Comment: @TylerH I don't think so. After spending that much effort on a question, the user is highly likely to convince themselves it's not a duplicate even when it is. They're also not going to want to spend much time examining the suggested questions for solutions. Furthermore, the specifics they flushed out while writing the question will give them more reasons to consider it dissimilar, resulting in even greater frustration if it does get closed as a dupe. The best time to point them elsewhere is before they've sunk much time into writing the question, when they'll be more willing to read.

Comment: @TylerH As for the quality of SO's search, the solution to that is a better search. The Wizard has already resulted in the search considering tags, so that's a sign we can hope for more improvement in the future. We might also want to advocate for some guidance to use an actual search engine in addition to SO's built in search, or maybe even the direct inclusion of some results from one as part of the wizard.

Comment: @TylerH One more thing: "And you should think of the time spent formulating the question as 'research effort' rather than 'wasted time' since you seem hung up on that." **I** do, but most of the users who the wizard is targeting won't. The wizard isn't designed for SO veterans who are already dedicated to question quality and have the experience and mindset required to be willing to throw away an entire question after having written it. It's targeted to people who care a little bit about writing a decent question but who don't understand what SO was built to do or how to research practically.

Comment: @jpmc26 If users disagree something is a duplicate after spending time on it, that's fine, because they're in a better position to know that. They're also still going to end up getting their question closed as a duplicate if their wrong (if enough users see it in time). It also ...doesn't matter... if new users are aware that their efforts are good practice for researching a problem; they're still doing the work. Have you ever seen Karate Kid? I agree on the guidance to use an actual search engine; that should be prominent wherever advice is given in the process.

Comment: @TylerH "If users disagree something is a duplicate after spending time on it, that's fine, because they're in a better position to know that." As I described, very little of the time they spend will be in evaluating the potential duplicate, so no, they very often won't be in a better position to determine that. Think about it in terms of cost/benefit. After you've already paid the cost of writing the question, is the payoff likely to be higher to pay the additional cost of reading a suggested dupe or of posting anyway and hoping someone will hand you answer on a silver platter?

Answer (score 26):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can title validation happen before allowing Next? or not change the focus until the title passes validation?

If you put a simple title like "Test" and hit Next it will move the view to focus on the next input field (No manual scrolling was done here, hitting next automatically scrolled to focus the next field hiding the title input):
[image: What are the details of your problem? focus view after hitting next from the title stage]

I actually have to scroll back up to see that my title was invalid:
[image: Title field with "Title must be at least 15 characters." error message and details field active for input]

Presumably this would need to be handled during the review phase before posting the question, but personally I feel that it would be beneficial to let users know that they've not actually completed a step before they move on to the next.

---

There's also no feedback at all for putting an existing title in the title field:

[image]

Which is an exact copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809)'s title

I can get all the way to the "Review your question" phase with a duplicate title if I just click through the duplicates list:

[image]

Even if I do go through the list of duplicate options we have a lot of questions with names like "Why doesn't my code work?" which may have an exact duplicate title while also not answering *my* specific question. I think there should be some indication that this title cannot be used at some point during the workflow rather than at the very end.

Comment: This new workflow performs duplicate question searches after the Tags step. We now also include tags in the dupe search to hopefully help make it a bit more accurate.

Comment: I understand, and I agree that considering tags is helpful in selecting duplicates. My point about the duplicate title piece is that I feel at some point during this workflow the user should be notified they cannot use that title. I've updated my answer to clarify that point.

Comment: There are certain validations (like duplicate title) that are currently performed only at the end of the process, that we would like to move up to be more immediate after text is changed. This is one of them. Though these changes wont make it into the current version being tested.

Comment: This isn't even about complex validations like duplicate title. You can enter a title that consists of only 4 characters, the UI will display a red error message telling you it's too short, but it still enables you to move onto the "Next" step. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 20):

This is a rather bad workflow for avoiding duplicate questions.

### Purpose of locating duplicate question in Ask page

Finding duplicates has two purposes. Helping users to find answers to their questions  if they already exist and preventing duplicate questions from being asked. If user can find the duplicate, posting an additional question would not be a *good sign post* and would just add clutter to the site.

### Finding the best duplicate candidates

There are two crucial parts for duplicate finding. First is the title that should contain the most relevant aspects of the problem and the tags that should focus the search into areas of relevant technology.

For instance, if I want to learn how to "Pass by reference vs pass by value" in Java, then showing duplicates for C++ or C# is not very helpful.

Main ingredients for successful duplicate search:

- Title
- Tags

### Old Ask page

The main problem with the old Ask page was that duplicates were looked for after the Title was entered, but Tags were the last, and they were not used for focusing the search to relevant technology. Because of that it was hard to find appropriate duplicates when asking questions.

Duplicate search results also don't show question tags, which are crucial for finding previously asked duplicate questions.

Taking "Pass by reference vs pass by value" in Java as an example, when searching for duplicates, the first candidates are about C++ and C#, but you cannot see that until you open the question. After opening the first three results and not finding anything Java related, this becomes a very frustrating experience.

### New Ask page

The new ask page uses both Title and Tags when looking for duplicates and that results with more accurate search results. But Tags are still the last thing you enter when asking a question and now locating duplicates happens after you have fully written your question.

At that point if you can find the duplicate you will be frustrated because you wasted your time writing a complete question before you were offered possible solutions.

Another option will be that you will either not bother with figuring out whether offered questions solve your problem at all or you will decide to post your question anyway. As a result your question may get closed and even downvoted which is also a frustrating experience. And the site has to deal with another question that didn't have to be posted in the first place.

### Solution

The best solution in preventing asking unnecessary questions without frustrating the asker is to offer the best possible duplicates as soon as possible. In other words when both Title and Tags are entered, but nothing else.

That requires that you move Tags to the top. Before or after the Title, it does not make much difference, but those two must be entered first and then it is time to offer duplicates.

Only after no appropriate duplicate is found, it is appropriate to fill the body of the question.

Comment: Does the duplicate search take into account the body of the question? If it does, you'd want duplicates to be the last thing you see, even if you've wasted time writing the question. SO duplicate search is notoriously rubbish at actually finding duplicates so it's worth giving it the best possible shot at succeeding.

Comment: The search on the wizard uses title and tags. Moving tags up (or the title down) is something that we would consider on a future iteration of the wizard. For the initial test it will stay as-is.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Moving Title down is not the right thing to do, moving Tags up is. You want to show possible duplicates before people fully write their question. Both Title and Tags need to be on the very top, which one of those will be first is less important.

Comment: _“the title that should contain the most relevant aspects of the problem”_ — This requires debugging skills. Most new devs will focus on some irrelevant phenomena without digging deeper to find the actual culprit, e.g. _“My HTML5 canvas game doesn’t draw the circles for the car tires correctly!”_ when it _really_ should be _“How to convert a string to a number?”_. (If they had these skills, Stack Overflow would probably have less than 10 % of the questions posted daily.) This weakens your argument that the title should be first to aid with dupe search; the opposite may actually be beneficial.

Comment: @Clonkex _“even if you’ve wasted time writing the question”_ — Either you “waste” time writing a question or you “waste” time debugging a problem yourself (or, of course, you put zero effort in a question…). There are plenty of cases where users have solved their problem _while_ writing out their question. Even if it’s not about debugging, sometimes this is a necessary (or at least very helpful) mental process to just type out a specific question. Focusing more on encouraging new users to share their research, would probably lead to more users eventually finding the answer themselves.

Comment: "*If user can find the duplicate, posting additional question would not represent good sign post*" This is not necessarily true. One can find a question via search and still be capable of crafting a good 'sign post' question that duplicates it.

Comment: @TylerH I am not focusing on exceptional questions, but by questions asked by new users who commonly haven't done any research. Questions that are not good duplicates, but might not be asked if asker is presented with appropriate duplicate or at least nudged to search more before asking the question.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Not all questions are debugging questions. I am also not talking about questions where writing it down you figure out the answer and you give up asking on your own. I am saying if there is a point if showing possible duplicates, then it should be done as soon as possible and not at the end when question is fully written and is only single click away from posting.

Comment: I agree that "Similar questions" should be shown earlier in the process. If the body is used to suggest similar questions, the suggestions could be presented twice, once after Title + tags, and a second time after the body is written as a "Refined" list (possibly none of the questions previously shown)

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Discarding changes leaves the title.

NB: I can  only reproduce it on Firefox (current version 98). Not on Chrome.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start writing a question.

   - If it is relevant: I used [the link that forces the wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?force-wizard=true).
2. Enter title and then click **Next**.

   - I used "Test title goes here now"
3. Enter some text in the "What are the details of your problem?" field and click **Next**.
4. Enter some text in the "What did you try and what were you expecting?" field.
5. Click **Discard Draft** and confirm.

Expected: All the information is gone or the page naviages away from the wizard. 
Actual: user is left on the page, "What are the details of your problem?" and "What did you try and what were you expecting?" fields are cleared, but the title is left.

[image: Screen recording of the error. It follows the steps described above and after step 5 (clicking Discard Draft) the title is left in place]

Comment: Could not reproduce, did they already fix it?

Comment: @MrMythical still behaves the same for me. I'm on Firefox 98. The short reproduction steps is to enter 20 characters in the title field and then click Discard, which will still leave you with the title.

Comment: I'm on Google Chrome, and I still can't reproduce

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and it doesn't behave like I described. Seems to be related to Firefox. I'll add this to the description.

Comment: Can also reproduce this in Firefox Nightly 100.0a1. The tags also remain.

Comment: Can’t reproduce this 100 %, but: When this happens and when reloading the page, the tags field is focused and the page scrolls down to this part. That’s suboptimal UX.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I cannot get the tags to be focused but in general, reloading seems to not play nice with the form. If you fill the second field (first after the title) and reload, it saves the value. But if you fill the third field and reload, it wipes the information from it but leaves the information in the second. It's weird.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox Dev 99.0b6. tags also remain, even though the field is disabled at the beginning of the wizard

Answer (score 18):

Can we please have more prominent warnings about posting images of code?

When an image is uploaded, the asker should be prompted to confirm that they're not posting a screenshot of their code. (Maybe even with some image recognition magic to have a guess at what's code and what isn't.)

P.S. in the "Describe your problem" box, the warning for not including images of code doesn't exist:

[image: "Describe your problem" box]

Comment: A warning pre-image insert is on our list of things that we want to do in the future for this. It wont make the current test. And this will not include any image recognition magic.

Comment: Can I suggest that it require an action for the asker to confirm that they're not posting an image of code.

Comment: that is exactly what we are planning

Comment: Is posting images of code not the most important thing to nip in the bud?

Comment: Rather than just a warning we should go back to disallowing new users from posting images of code.

Answer (score 11):

There isn't any validation that they actually entered something sensical:

[image]

It's ready to let me post this.

Obviously, in-depth checking would be quite difficult, but ensuring that there's multiple words at the very least would probably be a good idea.

I only mention this because I have seen, on *many* occasions, users simply spamming text to get around filters. At least requiring some spaces, or ensuring that the body has some common words ("the", "a", "to") seems like easy, cheap checks to do on the front-end.

---

Also, 30-40 characters is a *very* small amount of text to formulate a proper question. There may be some historic/canonical questions that are very short because they're so self-explanatory; but those would by far be the minority. Even 100-characters is barely anything.

Comment: I absolutely agree that input like this should be hard-blocked from submission by the system. Anything I'd flag as abusive on should be forbidden. Failure to enforce length limits has been a problem for *years*. [I tried to argue way back in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174097) that "*You need more than 16 words to ask a question. If you don't, your question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. It is impossible to state your problem, disclose your language/technology/environment, and briefly describe what you have already tried to solve the problem in any fewer than 30–50 words."*

Comment: An AI filter that detects gibberish would probably be better than hard coded rules. Plus such an AI probably already exists for comment sections and forums.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Add ability *and good guidance* for posting [self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

The new question wizard does not allow for writing a self-answer like the old one could where a user could write the question and answer pair at the same time and post them together.

I assume this is planned for a later stage but would still like to track the absence of the feature for now.

In addition, [there should be good instructions about self-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting) baked into the wizard. Thus if a user wants to post a self-answer they should be guided through that process, as well.

Self-answers are hard, even for experienced users. One common problem I find is that the question part should still be *a question* that can be answered. Often users would write a question and answer it, yet the query is formulated such that it cannot be answered by anybody other than themselves:

- there might be details missing
- not enough clarity to choose a solution
- the answer might not even fit to the question

Users should be reminded that the question part still needs to fit the rules by itself, without it relying on the answer to justify it.

Comment: We intentionally decided not to include self-answers as a feature of the wizard. Examining the data from Jan 2021 through min Feb 2022, there were 435K "first questions". Of these, only 21 were self-answered at the time of question creation (18.6K were self-answered at a later point in time). So given that this is something that is almost completely unused for first askers, and adds additional complexity to the asking process, we decided to leave it out.

Comment: You need at least 15 reputation to post an instant self-answer, so most new askers don't have the ability to provide a self-answer.

Comment: @Smitop Most is not all. I saw an example today of a user with more than 100 rep, who was still labelled "new user". They tried to post a self-answer and apparently got tripped up by the new wizard. This prompted my FR. I think what's often overlooked is that a new user could still be an expert who wants to contribute to the knowledge base, not just a person who expects a solution to problem. The exclusion of these people feels a bit...sand-y.

Comment: I recently asked my first question, which I wanted to be a self-answered community wiki, but could neither set it as a community wiki, nor answer it myself. I understand I'm in the minority (11k, first question), but it was still a PITA to have to post the question, flag for a moderator to make it a community wiki (something as yet not done), and wait for a close/reopen cycle to be able to add my own answer so that people could grok the purpose.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I spotted a little typo here: `entirely` -> `entirety`

[image]

Comment: A very long time ago this was the kind of comment I'd come up with in a code review. A typo! I found a typo in the variable name! I guess the skill remains after all these years :D

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The <kbd>Next</kbd> button is styled like a submit button, but the form cannot be submitted by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the title and tags input fields.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the "review your question" stage, the text editor keeps the "markdown" setting from the previous stage, however is always displaying rich-text content:

[image: Sample text that is not shown as markdown]

Toggling off and back on actually changes the editor to display the raw markdown.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty close tbh

You managed to get the relevant details in before the tags, and even display a list prior to posting once all the data is compiled. Awesome.

For some reason the duplicate search isn't working as intended though I think.

Example question I entered into the wizard:

Title: how to sort an array
Body: i hav this array: 1,2,55,210391203,18,9,42,-3
can it be sorted with some javascript?
Tried: I tried using a heapsort but it didn't work out.
Tags: javascript

Search result: [How to sort an array from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530446/how-to-sort-an-array-from-an-object)

---

It's close... I guess? But really if you want to help these new users, connect them with the content they need. The biggest thing that new users don't understand is the gravitas associated with actually posting a question. Sometimes they are just looking for word associations or even for comment suggestions. Showing them a relevant duplicate would open that door.

This situation should show one of the massively used posts as a search result. Even if I search for: -- how to sort an array [javascript] -- it will provide the relevant posts, of which some have thousands of votes. If this is to succeed, the duplicate suggestion "does this answer your question" section needs to have its accuracy dialed in, and it needs to also be more visible and easier to interact with. As it stands it is difficult to tell it scrolls, and it could benefit from being a little more difficult to bypass.

In all honesty, the goal here should be to have users stop at the "does this answer your question" and not ask because a lot of the time, that content exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is really nice! I believe it is certainly going to help new users posting quality questions. One suggestion would be to automatically insert section headers as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You do realize that we don't want questions with these section headers literally included? They're meant to help remind you of the type of information that should be included, but questions shouldn't actually use this formatting. They should be written as questions, using natural English.

Answer (score -6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Too.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Much.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Unused.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Space.

---

This is how the new question wizard page looks like on my screen. There are heaps of unused space due to the `max-width: 1264px;` rule that could be better spent either by stretching the question textarea to reduce the need for vertical scrolling or adding more useful tips for the question asker (note that I am not advocating for filling every nook and cranny with text, it's just one of the possible avenues of improving the usage of screen real estate on wider screens).

[image: screenshot of the new wizard with indication of unused space on the left,, right, and the top of the screen]

There is so much unused space that one could literally fill it with randomly fetched cat images (full userscript coming soon, but I threw together a quick demo because why not [see source code below]!)

[image: screenshot of the new wizard page with generated cat images]

```js
(async () => {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    document.head.append(style);

    const { sheet } = style;

    sheet.insertRule(`.cats-wrapper > .container {
        width: unset;
    }`);

    sheet.insertRule(`.cats-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
    }`);

    sheet.insertRule(`.cats-column {
        flex-basis: 15%;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }`);

    sheet.insertRule(`.cats-item {
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        margin: 20px;
        border-radius: 5%;
    }`);

    const catApiKey = localStorage.getItem("cat-api-key");
    if (!catApiKey) {
        return;
    }

    const mainContainer = document.querySelector("body > .container");
    if (!mainContainer) {
        return;
    }

    const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.classList.add("cats-wrapper");

    document.body.replaceChild(wrapper, mainContainer);
    wrapper.append(mainContainer);

    const leftCatColumn = document.createElement("div");
    leftCatColumn.classList.add("cats-column");

    const rightCatColumn = leftCatColumn.cloneNode();

    const catImg = document.createElement("img");
    catImg.classList.add("cats-item");
    catImg.style.visibility = "none";

    const cloneTemplateImg = () => {
        const clone = catImg.cloneNode();
        clone.addEventListener("load", () => {
            clone.style.visibility = "visible";
        });
        return clone;
    };

    const numCatsInColumn = 6;

    const catItemsBase = new Array(numCatsInColumn).fill(0);
    const leftCatItems = catItemsBase.map(cloneTemplateImg);
    const rightCatItems = catItemsBase.map(cloneTemplateImg);

    leftCatColumn.append(...leftCatItems);
    rightCatColumn.append(...rightCatItems);

    mainContainer.before(leftCatColumn);
    mainContainer.after(rightCatColumn);

    const catUrl = new URL("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search");
    catUrl.search = new URLSearchParams({
        size: "med",
        mime_types: "png",
        limit: numCatsInColumn * 2
    }).toString();

    while (true) {
        const res = await fetch(catUrl, {
            headers: { "x-api-key": catApiKey }
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
            break;
        }

        const catImages = await res.json();

        document.querySelectorAll(".cats-item").forEach((img, idx) => {
            const { url } = catImages[idx];
            img.src = url;
        });

        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 5 * 60 * 1e3));
    }
})();
```

---

Please consider either removing the width restriction or filling in the blanks with extra guidance and / or tips (such as reminders to properly format questions, avoid salutations and signatures, etc).

Comment: Welcome to every recent design change on SE. _"Information density"_ must be a forbidden phrase with the SE designers

Comment: Not filling every part of the screen with more information might help new users with focusing on writing their question without being overwhelmed.

Comment: –1 for cats instead of unicorns and red freehand circles

Comment: -1 because this page isn't meant to be information-dense. It's purely meant to guide new users to write a good question, and I don't see how squishing everything up would benefit it. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: What @Clonkex and mkrieger1 said. The goal isn't to use every pixel on the screen. It is to give a clear path to users for writing their question, with contextual tips and instructions that are easy to spot. And "filling in the blanks with extra guidance and / or tips" and making a wall of text is a pretty good way to ensure that none of the guidance will be read.

Comment: @CodyGray dang, indeed, should've been unicorns :) thanks for the idea. The good old freehand circles seems to be too much work for a joke script, though

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is not about making the page look like a NYT newspaper effectively cancelling its goal of being useful to new users but rather using the space moee eefectively. It can be anything: textarea stretching, small pieces of tips, a bit larger fonts/icons, etc.

Comment: @YaakovEllis this was less about additional guidance (which would be nice to have, IMO) and more about effectively using the screen space on wider screens. The is just too much space unused on those. For instance, there is no harm in allowing the textareas to stretch more than the current max width

Comment: @YaakovEllis I get the point but the amount of unused space is ridiculous. At least one or two tips should be added. It doesn't even look good, and that's one of the reasons.