# Punctuation characters being escaped in code

Tags: bug, status-review, code, stacks-editor

For the past couple of days, it seems that when users paste code into their questions, but don't put it into a proper code block, many punctuation characters are being automatically escaped with backslash. So when I reformat it into a correct code block, I now also have to remove all these backslashes.

For instance, see the edit history of [How to pass blank parameters to a script called in crontab (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610146/how-to-pass-blank-parameters-to-a-script-called-in-crontab-linux). The original question contained

```
- \* \* \* \* \* myscript.sh A B "" C D
```

I removed the backslashes when I reformatted it.

Characters that are being escaped include `*`, `[`, `]`.

Is this a SO change to the question editor? Or is it coming from somewhere else? I've seen it in dozens of questions, so I don't think it's something individual users are doing.

Comment: The [timeline](//stackoverflow.com/posts/71610146/timeline#history_9831bc20-aedc-4ff1-b382-3ed9e40b23f6) reveals that this post was created using the [new wizard](/q/416735/4642212) which uses the [Stacks editor](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/289905) which has [many problems](/a/416331/4642212).

Comment: That's it. I was searching for recent questions containing "backslash" or "escape", and didn't find anything. The question about the Stacks editor is relatively old.

Comment: The worst part is that the editor probably did the right thing. If you paste code in rich text mode outside of a code block, those characters _should_ be escaped in the (markdown) source so the text remains the way you pasted it. Fixing ill-formatted code might become a lot more cumbersome in the future if this editor goes live.

Comment: What we probably need is better help in the wizard for posting code blocks.

Comment: What we need is for SE to stop pushing the piece of junk which is the new editor without fixing the known existing problems. They've had substantially more than a year and a half to fix that thing, yet they haven't done so and keep pushing it everywhere they see a new opportunity to use it. Fix the problems ***before*** forcing people to use it.

Comment: Another recent example: [Javascript not working in html inline code](//stackoverflow.com/q/71613856/4642212).

Comment: Possibly related: *[Is the new editor's inline code tool supposed to break up code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416801/)*

Comment: Remember, everyone, that the Stacks Editor is Open Source at https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor.

Comment: How, exactly, does that help *anyone*, @pppery? Who would ever want to use that broken pile of trash?

Comment: My point was that someone could, in theory, fix the bug themselves rather than whining at Stack Exchange. I'm taking no position on whether the new editor is a good idea.

Comment: @pppery From the looks of it, it seems to be broken by design. This is not something one can just whip up a qick fix for in their spare time.

Comment: I was surprised to have to make an edit to fix an occurrence of this [in the wild](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71630967/revisions) today.  I'm glad I was kind about encountering it and just repaired the damage like a good janitor as it wasn't the author's fault.

Comment: @Wyck Same here, albeit I didnt fix the code, but started to ask "how did that happen", and luckily some guy linked to here.

Comment: This has started happening again today, maybe because the new Ask Wizard was deployed.