# Disable the Stacks editor in the new Ask Wizard

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stacks-editor, ask-question-wizard

Please, I kindly ask you to disable the flawed Stacks editor for new users. Most new users don't know how to manually solve the issues caused by this editor which leads to garbage posts and broken code.

There are a lot of issues with the new editor, but the primary two that caused the biggest harm are:

- Putting each line of code in a separate code block e.g. [Codemirror searchfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712228/codemirror-searchfilter)
- Escaping special characters in code when pasting it into the editor, e.g. [https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/2558/Identity-Server-Error---Microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697888/https-support-abp-io-qa-questions-2558-identity-server-error-microservices)

Please disable this editor as soon as possible. It's a terrible experience for new users and it's really difficult to fix by the rest. Some users flag such posts as VLQ or downvote and close it immediately, even if it would have been an ok question otherwise.

Comment: better feature request: disable the Stacks editor, period. It's nowhere near usable anywhere. All the testing that can be done has been done at this point; the only thing to do now is implement fixes, which SE doesn't seem interested in

Comment: Both of these issues with the stacks editor are reported and tagged status-review: [escaping characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416802/15497888) and [breaking up code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416801/15497888)

Comment: Something this fundamentally broken shouldn't be left in to review taking it out, it should be taken out to review putting back in. Is there a `status-fatally-flawed`?

Comment: I haven't personally experienced any bugs with it, but because Markdown is easy to learn, disabling this shouldn't have too big of an impact.

Answer (score -29):

The stacks editor is not going to be removed from the new Ask Wizard.

A lot of bugs have been fixed with the Stacks Editor recently. You can check out the issues scheduled for work, and submit new issues directly on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues).

Comment: Please at least give us an option in the post UI to revert to using the old editor. Or better yet, allow users to opt into the new editor the same way. It works fine enough if you write the markdown yourself (there are some rendering issues at times when previewing) but the WYSIWYG mode is clearly not ready for primetime yet.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I'd argue that even the Markdown mode isn't ready for prime time. I don't recall a time I've used that editor and *not* had it loose the entire contents of the post, at least once, while I was editing. Maybe it hasn't lost the entire contents some times when I'm only making a very minor change, but if I'm doing anything significant, I have to *plan on* having it loose the entire contents of the post.

Comment: As long as this editor is enabled, the safest and easiest option is to write markdown in a notepad and then paste into the new editor.

Comment: @Makyen I've never had that happen to me, but *yikes* - The worst I've had are issues with formatting getting mangled or removed when switching modes.

Comment: *"A lot of bugs have been fixed with the Stacks Editor recently."* Wow, and yet it's *still* bug-riddled to the point of being completely unusable? Here I had assumed it just wasn't getting any better because it wasn't getting any developer attention. All that hard work fixing bugs, and yet it's still unusable and roundly rejected by the userbase? That does not bode well for the future. Sounds like it's time to do what we've been saying all along and scrap it. See also: [sunk-cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost#Fallacy_effect)

Comment: Have those critical bugs been added to an (automatic) test suite?

Comment: The best way to get the team's attention for Stacks-Editor bugs is to [file an issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues). Round tripping / markdown (de)serialization bugs are among our top priority, so please submit any issues you're finding along those lines!

Comment: Has there been any thought put into actually having someone on staff *test* the product, instead of expecting volunteer users to do all the testing and file bugs, @Ben?

Comment: @CodyGray no need for the condescension. We are testing the product all the time (we use it every day on our own internal SO Team) and there is testing built-in to the editor as well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I am a software tester. "Using" a product and "testing" it are not the same thing and one cannot stand in for the other. If your standard of testing is whether or not the developers can use it, no wonder it's such a disaster. Get a software test professional on your team, stat. I can't stand it when people claim that testers aren't real programmers and then dump out garbage like the stack editor.

Comment: @YaakovEllis how long are we going to have two editors on the site? The key-bindings, icons, etc. are different for both of them so it is a confusing experience for new users as most of the help center articles etc. are still describing how to use the current editor only. See this recent post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427286/unable-to-post-code-and-error-on-stack-overflow-while-asking-question-not