# New editor is inserting www.stackoverflow.com instead of the intended URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, ask-question-wizard, stacks-editor

This happened to me yesterday in Stack Overflow for Teams but I assumend that was my mistake, but now I have found a question from a new user that it's very likely that didn't noticed this problem.

The following search
[url:https://www.stackoverflow.com created:2023](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%20created%3A2023) returns 162 posts having this problem.

---

Modifing the `created:` operator

|  | Results |
| --- | --- |
| [2022](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%20created%3A2022) | 384 |
| [2008..2021](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%20created%3A2008..2021) | 101 |

---

Markdown examples:

This has two links, the first is OK but the second, is use "this page" as the link text, so only the OP is able to fix it.

```
A combination of [this script](https://gist.github.com/bpmore/0337b4ac1fc9110975e70fc5df53203f#file-sort-tabs-txt) and the second answer on [this page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) were the two that were giving me a working model. Now I turn to the masters to learn how to do it right.
```

```
I have tried [https://lumiamitie.github.io/r/pie-gauge-in-ggplot2/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)  by `proj=:polar` in Plots.jl, but doesn't solve it.
```

```
In my research, I came across similar questions such as:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph ](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
```

Comment: Repro'd easily, the new Stacks Editor put `www.stackoverflow.com` as the link placeholder on Markdown mode. Possibly status by-design.

Comment: Interesting. This explains why I've seen so much spam getting posted that links to `www.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: It appears to be a result of the hardcoded `dummyLink` in  [`insertCommonmarkLinkCommand` in Stacks Editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/a90570a01fd9b020eac854a148155dc7b0803284/src/commonmark/commands.ts#L587-L620). That dummy link has been in place for a very long time, I'm not sure what caused the changes to only recently take effect.

Comment: @HenryEcker it already happened at least [since March 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71560261/2821954), probably [the first post from the Wizard™ public test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416735/2821954).

Comment: Ahh, yes that makes more sense. This issue would've been present in the Stacks Editor from release of the Ask Wizard. I was mislead into thinking this was a recent issue because the search included in the question which limited search to just posts this year (which I did not notice). Thanks @AndrewT.

Comment: @HenryEcker The "problem" (URL) is present too in older posts (before 2022) but it grew up almost 4 times in 2022. Apparently it's growing quickly.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the search returned some false positives for posts that are really referring to other questions on SO (e.g. as additional context or duplicate). It doesn't search for the exact URL `https://www.stackoverflow.com` but more like `https://www.stackoverflow.com[*]`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been [fixed upstream](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/commit/151c4a8609e5b9719e616fdfcc0837c3c3e285c2) in the Stacks-Editor codebase. Once a new release has been cut and pulled into the core codebase, the fix will arrive network-wide. I do not currently have a time estimate for when this will happen.

As mentioned in the question comments, the default/dummy url was hardcoded to `"https://www.stackoverflow.com/"`, with a relevant `// TODO what dummy link to use?` comment on the line right above. The code was changed such that the domain from the *current* page will be used (e.g. `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/` on this site, `https://meta.stackexchange.com/` on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and so on).

Comment: If I'm understanding this answer correctly, there'd be effectively no change for Stack Overflow since using the current domain on Stack Overflow would result in the same value as the current dummy text `"https://www.stackoverflow.com/"`. If that's the case, I'm not sure how this addresses the issue posed in this question which that there are a significant number of posts whose links do not point to their intended destination (as demonstrated in many of the posts in the linked searches as well as the markdown examples at the end of the question).

Comment: I understand that this is likely, in large part, a usage error in that the user is overwriting the link text with their URL instead of replacing the href portion of the markdown. Regardless, at the current scale, this has resulted in several hundred posts since the release of the ask wizard (and that is still being used by a relatively small number of users). My concern is that this will continue to be an issue, and one that will grow as more users begin to interact with the Stacks Editor.

Comment: @HenryEcker Ah, I'm understanding the concern a bit more clearly. This post is more along the lines of "a UX issue is causing careless user behavior" rather than "the hardcoded dummy url is incorrect". I think the fix for this may be simple: rather than highlighting the _text_ on markdown link insert, highlight the _url_ instead. In that case, careless user behavior will persist, but it'll be the link _text_ that is incorrect rather than the link _destination_. Is that a fair assessment of your concerns? If so, I can pretty quickly alter the code to reflect that behavior instead.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair understanding of my concern and my interpretation of this post. I think having the link destination highlighted by default would be a great thing to try. The non-descriptive text link will be significantly more noticeable to the author (or other editors) in the post than a link like "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)" which seems fine when looking at the post, but doesn't actually direct to the correct location.

Comment: Update: Stacks-Editor v0.8.7 highlights the link destination by default (as opposed to the link text). This way we hope to reduce scenarios when a user would copy/paste straight away after clicking the "insert link" button and leaving therefore a dummy link. Stacks-Editor v0.8.7 has already been deployed to all networks.