# The Ask Wizard's "What did you try" question is eliciting a lot of useless information

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-wizard

The Ask Wizard asks:

> What did you try and what were you expecting?
>
> Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what
> actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters.

And we are getting *lots* of questions which say such things as:

> [I have tried ChatGPT which sadly failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042902/convert-a-word-list-to-a-csv)

and

> [I asked chatGPT how to fix the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011016/my-java-discoverylisteners-arent-working-i-cant-detect-nearby-devices-with-ja)

and

> [I tryed and searched but i cant find for nodejs i only find for python but i dont use python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039277/i-was-trying-to-create-custom-answers-with-nodejs)

and

> [I searched two days on net but couldn't find anything that I can apply, so it would be good to recommend me a roadmap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041671/can-i-take-a-map-from-the-player-before-the-game-starts)

This isn't useful information (and the mentions of ChatGPT are depressing). We need information about how the asker tried to solve the problem, not vague descriptions of their research techniques.

Can the Wizard's question be edited to better elicit useful information from the asker?

Comment: [They're preparing you...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388401/357051)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think so. This is not an issue with the wizard but with the skill level of the person putting the lack of information there. They really do not know, they come to Stack Overflow to outsource the responsibility of finding out. As long as the wizard is merely a guide rather than a gatekeeper, this'll be what you have to live with.

Comment: even worse, *"I have tried nothing because I don't know"*

Comment: @Gimby Author skills are a problem, but all site documentation could be much clearer & specific.

Comment: The Ask Wizard [does improve spam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K19Sg.png). Can you imagine how much worse this would be without the wizard?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of "I'm expecting an answer"...

Comment: And what wording would you suggest...? Something like "*What did you try and what result/behaviour were you expecting? (Post your code.)*"...?

Comment: I'd suggest making it not mandatory so that if someone feels it isn't necessary for their question they can skip it. We've already established that not every question *needs* "what have you tried" to be a valuable contribution. Requiring it just results in people who feel they don't need it dumping fluff into it.

Comment: The only thing that should go into that box is an MRE - and the help text should spell that out and link to it. Everything that is not a debugging question does not require an attempt and the wizard should not imply otherwise.

Comment: I have noticed a lot of questions that have an additional line at the end that seems to summarise their question. I didn't know what was happening until I noticed that there is a "What did you try?" prompt when creating Questions. Has this always been there?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein only since [the Ask Wizard was released](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/ask-wizard-for-new-users-feature-test-is-complete)

Comment: Canonical duplicate? [Can the text in the Ask Question wizard asking the OP to describe what they were expecting be clarified?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424310/can-the-text-in-the-ask-question-wizard-asking-the-op-to-describe-what-they-were)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe rephrasing around the word *attempt* could be a way out?

Something like:

> Show your attempt at solving this problem, what you expected it to do, and how the actual result differed from what you expected. Minimum 20 characters.

Maybe even add “Ideally, show the minimal piece of code you wrote or used.” with a link to MRE – but I think keeping the prompt short increases chances of it being actually read.

I also think changing *Describe* to *Show* is just as key in this rephrasing, but it applies less to non-debugging questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I put the status-review tag on the wrong question...I'd intended to put it on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424310/208273) alongside my suggested solution.  I'd invite you to post your suggestion there as well, so that we have all the suggestions together.  Unfortunately, there's not a good way for me to move either my answer or yours over without destroying the existing comment discussions.

Comment: No worries, I’ve copied my answer over there @RyanM