# Can the text in the Ask Question wizard asking the OP to describe what they were expecting be clarified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-review, ask-question-wizard

I recently encountered a now-deleted question that ends with the following phrase:

> I expecting someone gonna help me to understand this and fix it immediately

My original thought was that the OP was just being rude. However, it was pointed out to me in SOCVR that the OP was probably just answering the last question on the question asking wizard: "What did you try and what were you expecting?"

Can the text be changed to explain that this should be what the OP was expecting their code/attempt to do, not what they're expecting the community to do with their question?

I don't have a great alternative phrasing, but here are a few possibilities off the top of my head:

- What did you try, and what did you expect would happen when you did that?
- Please provide clear steps for others to reproduce and understand your problem - what you tried, what you thought would happen when you did that, and actually happened instead.

Comment: The real truth is that users don't know how to read, as it's pretty clear: *"Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted."* - *"Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and why it didn’t meet your needs. Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a [mre]. Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."*

Comment: This seems to be *strongly* related to the recent [The Ask Wizard's "What did you try" question is eliciting a lot of useless information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424236/the-ask-wizards-what-did-you-try-question-is-eliciting-a-lot-of-useless-infor).

Comment: All that information is there, yet users *still* don't format thier questions, post images of code, and don't provide an MRE; despite their beliefs "I tried, but it doesn't work" is not a helpful statement.

Comment: @ThomA That particular text is clear, but unfortunately users appear to be ignoring it.

Comment: *"but unfortunately users appear to be ignoring it."* And that is the real problem; users don't read. It's not a new problem, and unfortunately not a solvable one (unless we start making them take a test before they ask of the contents on the [tour] and [help], and they need to pass it before they can actually post a question).

Comment: "*Can the text be changed to explain that this should be what the OP was expecting their code/attempt to do, not what they're expecting the community to do with their question?*" why do you think that would help? The user already didn't actually read address the whole of "**What did you try** and what were you expecting?" I've bolder the part that the user's didn't respond to. They did also either misread, or misunderstood, or plain didn't really care about the second part, either. But the box is mandatory, so they probably put in the barest effort to cover the 20 character minimum limit.

Comment: The other common problem is to copy pasta the statement from their first text box into the second. That *really* annoys me; it almost always gets an instant downvote from me.

Comment: "*unfortunately users appear to be ignoring it.*" right. And why exactly would changing the text that users already ignore help? Seems like they'd just be ignoring the new text, however clear it is.

Comment: @VLAZ The text that ThomA cited is off to the side, which makes it much easier to ignore in my opinion (and many people clearly *are* ignoring it).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine [not all of it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiCKi.png).

Comment: I'd much rather see the second box in the wizard gone completely. I have not yet seen a single time it was used correctly.

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted the text that is *immediately above the second body box* changed. The one that reads "What did you try and what were you expecting?" and which the user you cite ignored at least half off. Is *that* the text you want changed? And *if so*, would changing it make users stop ignoring it like they already did?

Comment: An [excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76074930/2029983) of reading. /sarcasm

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that's the text that should be changed. We obviously can't force OPs to read, but the text on the side is eminently ignorable.

Comment: We *can* force them to read, but holding a gun to their head just doesn't scale. Plus it's kind of impolite.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine the text *above* the text box is also ignorable. Again, I don't see what *changing* the text would accomplish. Given that, yet again, we have concrete evidence that *it is currently being ignored*.

Comment: **Thank you**, I've seen a number of these "I'm expecting someone to explain this" / "I'm expecting an answer with code" / "I'm expecting a solution" and I couldn't understand why. Now I know. Those bits of the questions tell us that those particular people **are** reading the text, they're just misinterpreting it (or taking the piss), which means rewording to address that misunderstanding is reasonable. It won't make the people who don't read it read it, but it may help people stop coming across as flatly rude with the "I'm expecting" thing. I like both of your suggestions.

Comment: It is reasonable to change the question being asked. I just don't expect the text being put there to become any better as a result of it. These people are here to outsource the responsibility, at least this person was being honest about it. I'm never going to call that rude, it is actually quite decent of them to admit it.

Answer (score 11):

Consider something like:

> **If you have tried to solve this, describe what you tried and what you expected to happen when you tried that.**

- It's harder to confuse with "what *do* you expect [from asking this question]?"
- It still conveys the importance of describing your expectations.
- It makes it clear that an attempt isn't required.

Now, the problem with this (though also the current phrasing) is, as [pointed out in the comments on another meta question asking about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427940/remove-what-were-you-expecting-from-the-ask-question-wizard#comment985581_427940): what if it's just a how-to question and they haven't tried anything relevant to the question, and they just need to know where to start?

To solve that, I'd also **make filling in the second box optional**.  We don't need to know that [they asked an AI, searched the web, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424236/208273)  Just let them leave it blank if it's not helpful.

I'd probably A/B test at least that second part to see if it makes it better or worse.  The phrasing could also be A/B tested.

Comment: Well, users are not reading and/or ignoring the text as it currently is. I don't think "*If you have tried to solve this*" would make them read the whole thing. Most likely users would just engage in selective reading again and fill in some garbage information that barely even fits whatever they misinterpret the question is.

Comment: @VLAZ I think it's _harder_ to misread, at least.  The current one is one similar-looking word away from "what are you expecting?"; this is structured to make that misinterpretation harder.

Comment: Any incremental fix like this is completely missing the point. The entire concept behind the AQW is utterly flawed, and demonstrates a misunderstanding of the site's goal so profound it seems like it has to be intentional.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree with you that there are more fundamental issues, but I think that the incremental fixes of changing the text and especially making the box optional are simple fixes that would move it in the right direction without a lot of development effort.  I do think that in a world where user retention is a major concern, focusing significant effort on the new user experience _should_ be a priority.  But alas, I am not in charge of product direction.

Comment: I simply don't believe that users are currently misled by the UI. The ones that put in garbage in the box either don't care or deliberately don't follow the instructions for it. The major reason they fill in garbage is because they are trying to do the minimum work needed. So, changing the wording won't make them care more. Making the box optional would help, I don't disagree with that. My problem is changing wording as a measure for users who *do not read*.

Comment: @VLAZ "users who do not read" cannot be expected to participate in a site that has any standards beyond those seen on Quora or a Youtube comments section, so.

Comment: If they haven't tried to solve the problem on their own yet, should they be allowed to post the question at all? I don't remember ever seeing a case where someone who hasn't tried to solve the problem actually asked a [real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I feel this question is real: [Why can the `async` and `await` keywords be assigned to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56869954) If it's not, then how can it be made real? What do I add for something I've tried?

Comment: @VLAZ That's definitely a real question, but it's asking a specific question about why specific code behaves a specific way. I was more referring to "I'm trying to write a program to navigate a map, I haven't tried anything because I don't even know where to get started" type questions. Those are almost never real questions.

Comment: Yes, I agree those are not useful and close-worthy. Usually because they lack focus. But often for other problems. However, I'm objecting to requiring an attempt for all questions.

Comment: @VLAZ Incidentally, I upvoted the linked question (and its answer) because I found them to be interesting and informative.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine how-to questions that are properly focused don't require any attempts to be shared and there are many such good questions on Stack Overflow. For example here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-python) that's just a single line and is perfectly on-topic

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Fair point, that one does seem to be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any general advice for this box is going to work.

"The only thing that should go into that box is an MRE - and the help text should spell that out and link to it. Everything that is not a debugging question does not require an attempt and the wizard should not imply otherwise. – [MisterMiyagi Apr 18, 2023 at 16:36](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424236/the-ask-wizards-what-did-you-try-question-is-eliciting-a-lot-of-useless-infor#comment954472_424236)"

Roughly adjusting the text from the MRE help page to clearly spell out what is needed under what conditions should be more appropriate:

> When asking a debugging question, provide code that follows the guidelines of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Notably, **providing input here must be optional** as no MRE, failed attempts, or similar are needed for non-debugging questions.

Comment: Not sure I agree. In a “how to do  X” question showing a failed attempt is quite useful to find the misconception. Even useful in the repository of questions view (as opposed to catering to OP only) as misconceptions can be widespread, and obvious things for experienced users maybe less clear for newcomers

Comment: @Cimbali "quite useful" isn't the same as mandatory.

Comment: Sure but making the box entirely optional is pretty much the same as not putting a box at all. Maybe being able to disable the box with a “I have no idea where to start” checkbox or something like that?

Comment: @Cimbali If it's optional with a checkbox, that text should also clearly follow the rules and not imply an attempt/guess/idea is expected where none actually is. A checkbox with description such as "This is not a debugging question." could work.

Comment: @Cimbali failed attempts are *extremely bad* for "how to" questions. Because they drastically change the direction of the answers. Instead of creating a question useful for many others when they want to do foo, it's not a question of how to fix some flawed implementation of foo which, even with the code problems aside, might just be suboptimal. Or at the very least it might be one of many options. People who want to use foo might prefer a different approach which better fits their circumstances.

Comment: @VLAZ In my experience answers tend to reflect that. I often read things like “Your error is X but the better approach is Y” and then elaborating on Y.

Comment: @Cimbali in my experience, *very few* answerers do that. Most will do the minimum work needed to answer. Yes, there are people who leave good answers. But aren't the prevalent answer posters.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe rephrasing around the word *attempt* could be a way out?

Something like:

> Show your attempt at solving this problem, what you expected it to do, and how the actual result differed from what you expected. Minimum 20 characters.

Maybe even add “Ideally, show the minimal piece of code you wrote or used.” with a link to MRE – but I think keeping the prompt short increases chances of it being actually read.

I also think changing *Describe* to *Show* is just as key in this rephrasing, but it applies less to non-debugging questions.

<sub>(Copied from [this sister non `status-review` tagged question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424236/the-ask-wizards-what-did-you-try-question-is-eliciting-a-lot-of-useless-infor/427943) as suggested by @RyanM)</sub>