Why does Stack Overflow enforce "What did you try and what were you expecting?" when asking a question?
In this edit history, you can see an experienced user removed the "What did you try and what were you expecting?" section from my question minutes after I posted. I kind of agree with them removing this section. However, I couldn't post the question without it, and it wasn't the first time this happened with a question I asked.
What is the reason for this section, and why can't I ask something without it?

That section is only shown when you use the wizard; you can opt out using said wizard.

Note that they didn't exactly just remove it; they integrated the gist of it into the text of the rest of the question.  But your point stands that the structure is not always optimal (I'd make that box optional if it were up to me).

Because obviously we only want debugging questions (/s)

Considering how often I see stuff like, "I asked ChatGPT" and "I expected the program to work" I question the value of the prompts in the first place. At the very least the prompts need better wording.

@user4581301 see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424310.

tl;dr: this is not actually "enforced".
What you're seeing is one more in a long string of attempts by the site to implement half-baked technical solutions to problems identified by the community, with little to no understanding of the problem and a very shaky idea of how the site is actually supposed to work.
Your question was edited to integrate one important detail of what you tried into the prose of the question: the versions of Angular involved in the upgrade (16->17). Everything else you mentioned there was already implicit in your description of the problem, so there was no reason to restate it. (It's also good policy to start off troubleshooting questions with "I'm trying to...", so that the reader has a clear starting point to understand the problem.)
The "Ask Question Wizard" (2022) vs. Stack Overflow policy
It sounds like you're asking about the Ask Question Wizard (currently just called "Ask Wizard" in the UI) introduced in 2022. (My understanding is that there were previous attempts at implementing this sort of thing, but none were rolled out site-wide.) My understanding is that this is only mandatory for your first question. As an experienced user, you should be able to disable this by turning off the option at the top of the form (shown disabled in this screenshot):

The Wizard is apparently intended to be a proper tool for guiding new users step by step through asking a question, but it very much underdelivers on that promise. Basically it just forces you to go through the form step by step (it's often better to write the title last, so this is a mistake), and splits the main body of the question into two sections. The form promises that it will "merge" this content - which means literal concatenation, not anything intelligent. So, technically, this is a "more step-by-step approach" - exactly one step has been added, and you are constrained to take the steps in order.
Fundamentally there are two major categories of question that make sense to ask on Stack Overflow: the ones where you're trying to figure out why something went wrong in your existing code; and the ones where you simply want to know how to do some simple task. The form is oriented towards those "why" questions - the assumption is that every question will be such a "debugging" question (I dislike this term, because in my mind if you have a proper MRE then you have already done the relevant debugging and are just left with a question about understanding behaviour).
Telling us what you tried is only helpful for those questions. If you have a how-to question, then it doesn't make any sense to fill in details about what you tried, because there's no particular expectation that you tried anything. (That often makes the question worse, in fact.) Instead, what we really want is a proper specification of the task - it should be immediately possible to understand how input is provided and structured, and how output is presented; and it should be clear how to test a proposed solution - i.e., for any given input, others should be able to check the output produced and clearly know whether it's correct.
The prompt has also been widely misinterpreted - resulting in questions with strangely phrased noise at the end. (Sometimes new users don't even write a complete sentence here, but just something like "an answer to the problem". Sometimes they copy and paste the first box into the second.)
But really the worst part is that, while some questions should include such information, it usually makes no sense to list it separately at the end. The simple concatenation of the two text fields produces nonsense in many cases, and substandard clarity in most other cases. And really, it's normally impossible to give any clear explanation of "the details of the problem" without incorporating "what you expected". For example, if the problem is that the code crashes with an uncaught exception, generally it's completely redundant to say "I expected the code to run without exception". There are cases where the OP can't clearly explain why the code's actual result is unsatisfactory; but this kind of prompting just doesn't help with those cases. Usually those questions just get closed as unclear and the OP never manages to edit them to fix the problem (which often seems to result from just not being able to communicate well enough).

At a minimum, a properly designed "ask question wizard" would offer a completely different flow for the two kinds of questions I identified.

Splendid analysis and explanation.  (I didn't know any of this.)

I think "how do I do X"-questions should come with some evidence of effort invested by the asker. prompting the asker to do research (googling) would at least remind askers that they're supposed to do their homework, rather than just telling us genies their wish, and making it sound like a command to ChatGPT. I know we're not supposed to complain about or acknowledge the fact of lazy askers but most of the questions do fall in the categories of either "Lazy" or "Newbie biting off more than they can chew".

@ChristophRackwitz Why?  How does evidence of effort make the question more useful for the next person with the same problem?  My experience is that it usually tends to make them less useful, because the answers will tend to just point out a problem with the question's code, rather than containing a complete solution or addressing the question from first principles (perhaps the attempt was not optimal, even if done correctly).

fair point, @RyanM. questions are also for the next dude who has the same question... but also think of those that are expected to answer the question. we have some expectations. if these aren't met, chances drop. I would not recommend telling askers to ignore our expectations. we don't just interact with a question. we interact with the human who asks it.

@ChristophRackwitz The expectation is that the question is properly scoped and explained, and that answering it could be useful for others. Most of the time, lazy newbies dump a homework assignment, which is not properly scoped, or a confused mess that results from a lack of research. But sometimes they get lucky and, say, are the first to ask something like "how do I open and read a text file in BleedingEdgeLang?". Traditional documentation only offers a reference; Q&A fills in how-to guides and explanations that full documentation ought to have (according to some).

(Tutorials, of course, are out of scope; they need to be written entirely from a teacher's perspective, not framed by a learner's question. The point of a tutorial is that the teacher knows what needs to be taught.)
