# Remove "what were you expecting" from the Ask Question Wizard

Tags: feature-request, questions, ask-question-wizard

Something I've seen a bit lately is odd little one-liners at the bottom of questions. Some recent examples...

> Thanks in advance
>
> clear guidance what to focus on first and pay attention to from experienced developers
>
> ~ [Getting into Javascript- confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77910797/283366)

> But API response in not get refresh token
>
> I'm getting a refresh token
>
> ~ [I am not getting refresh token in LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77903926/283366)

I can only assume these come from the wizard's second textarea field: ***"What did you try and what were you expecting?"***.

[image: screenshot of the ask question wizard]

Some users are obviously focusing on the *"what were you expecting"* part and treating it like an optimistic wishlist.

As such, the way it just mashes the content of this field on to the end of the post leads to some very confusing structure.

---

Can this *please* be reworded to emphasise this as the part of the question where you show the code you're using and the result you get. For example:

> #### What did you try?
>
> Describe what you tried. Include your code or details of your program. Describe the result you received and how it differs from what you expected to happen.

Comment: Some focus on the "what did you expect" and fill in garbage like "an answer to my query" (seriously), others decide to focus on "what did you try" and still fill in garbage like "I tried many things" or even "I tried nothing".

Comment: In fact the "What did you try?" part is not suitable at all for "How to" questions where an attempt is not needed. It also similarly [elicits useless responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424236/the-ask-wizards-what-did-you-try-question-is-eliciting-a-lot-of-useless-infor). The Ask Wizard in general isn't great.

Comment: I mean, I open the wizard and the first thing it asks is for a title. The title it puts as an example is *"Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?"*. Now it is suggesting an R question where curation tends to be a lot more lenient, but for most other programming environments that question would be seen as very unresearched I fear. It is in examples like that where I truly see that the company wants this site to be just another Reddit, they just don't want to make the effort to come out and say that it is so.